# How to iterate through two columns in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

im trying to iterate through two columns in the csv file using python?, I heard that you have to import pandas for this, but im just struggling on the coding part.

```
import csv as csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('train.csv', 'rb'))  # Load in the csv file
header = csv_file_object.next()                   # Skip the fist line as it is a header
data=[]                                     # Create a variable to hold the data

for row in csv_file_object:                      # Skip through each row in the csv file,
    data.append(row[0:])                        # adding each row to the data variable
data = np.array(data)   



def number_of_female_in_class_3(data):
    for row in data.iterow:
        if row[2] == 'female' and row[4] == '3':
            sum += 1
```

The problem is the function **number_of_female_in_class_3** i want to go through two colunms, i want to go through column 2 to check if the rows contains the string 'female' and go through columns 4 and check if the status is '3'.If this is true then i want to increment 1 to **sum**.

I was wondering if someone can post a simple code on how to accomplish this?

here is the train.csv file im trying to retrieve.

```
**PassengerID** | **Survived** | **Pclass**   | **Name**  |  **Sex**   |
          1     |          0   |         3    |  mary     |  Female    |
          2     |          1   |         2    |  james    |  Male      |
          3     |          1   |         3    |  Tanya    |  Female    |
```

Thank you

Comment: You import `pandas` but don't use it. This is a good use case for it though, so it might be worth figuring out. See my answer. Hopefully you can easily reformat the data into a cleaner CSV and everything will 'just work'.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `pandas` can help you here.

I'm starting with a cleaner CSV:

```
PassengerID,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex
1,0,3,mary,female
2,1,2,james,male
3,1,3,tanya,female
```

If your CSV actually looks like what you posted (not really a CSV), then you will have some wrangling to do (see below). But if you can get `pandas` to eat it:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv')
>>> result = df[(df.Sex=='female') & (df.Survived==False)]
```

Results in a new `DataFrame`:

```
>>> result
             Survived  Pclass  Name     Sex
PassengerID                                
1                   0       3  mary  female
```

You can do `len(result)` to get the count you're after.

---

#### Loading that CSV

If you're stuck with that nasty CSV, you can get your `df` like so:

```
# Load using a different delimiter.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv', sep="|")

# Rename the index.
df.index.names = ['PassID']

# Rename the columns, using X for the bogus one.
df.columns = ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'X']

# Remove the 'extra' column.
del df['X']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
import csv

def number_of_female_in_class_3(data):
    # initialize sum variable
    sum = 0
    for row in data:
        if row[4] == 'Female' and row[2] == '3':
            # match
            sum += 1
    # return the result
    return sum

# Load in the csv file
csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('train.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='|')
# skip the header
header = csv_file_object.next()
data = []

for row in csv_file_object:
    # add each row of data to the data list, stripping excess whitespace
    data.append(map(str.strip, row))

# print the result
print number_of_female_in_class_3(data)
```

Some explanation:

First of all in your file you have Female with an uppercase F, secondly you had your column numbers backwards (gender in column 5 and class in column 3)
You need to initialize the sum variable to 0 before you start incrementing it.
numpy and pandas are not needed here although you need to apply the strip function to every element in each row to remove excess spaces (`map(str.strip, row)`) and also pass `delimiter='|'` into `csv.reader` because the default delimiter is a comma. Lastly you need to `return sum` at the end of you function.

Comment: It keeps on giving me 0

Comment: @Mr_Shoryuken it prints 2 for me using the data you posted. Did you copy and paste the above and try it?

Comment: It's also worth noting that using pandas is way slower (~100x slower for the small data set that you posted not as much as data set gets larger)

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

## Load CSV file 1 into a DataFrame

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")

## Load CSV file 2 into a DataFrame

df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

## Iterate through each row in df1

for i, row1 in df1.iterrows():

```
# Check if there is a matching row in df2 where col1+col2 equals row1['col1']+row1['col2']
match = df2[(df2['col1']+df2['col2']) == (row1['col1']+row1['col2'])]

# Check if there is a matching row in df2 where col1+col3 equals row1['col1']+row1['col3']
match2 = df2[(df2['col1']+df2['col3']) == (row1['col1']+row1['col3'])]

# Flag the matching rows in df1
if not match.empty:
    df1.loc[i, 'flag'] = 'match'
elif not match2.empty:
    df1.loc[i, 'flag'] = 'match2'
else:
    df1.loc[i, 'flag'] = 'no match'
```

## Save the updated df1 to a new CSV file

df1.to_csv("file1_flagged.csv", index=False)

Comment: this answer is an overkill to the problem from performance perspective